# Google Oauth authorised redirect URI cant accept /* at last of URL

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

ive been doing a stephen grider course and he creates a google oauth client id with authorised js orgins as http://localhost:5000 and authorised redirect URI as http://localhost:5000/* and google accepts it. But when i try the same it throws me an error for redirect URI as **Invalid redirect: Cannot contain a wildcard (*)**. And im not sure without this , further it will cause problems.Any way to solve this. Ive typed **http://localhost:5000/** as a temp solution. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

What ever course you are following must be very old I have been developing with Google for five years a wildcard redirect uri has not been allowed in that time.

> Authorized redirect URIs
>   For use with requests from a web server. This is the path in your application that users are redirected to after they have authenticated with Google. The path will be appended with the authorization code for access. Must have a protocol. Cannot contain URL fragments or relative paths. Cannot be a public IP address.

Redirect uri must be a path to the file you wish to use to handle your authorization.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URL you configure to the API console must be an *exact* string match to the redirect URL you use in your app. So for example, `http://localhost:5000` does *not* match `http://localhost:5000/` or `https:5000//localhost`. Thus a wildcard will never work.

Furthermore, it's very unusual for a redirect URL to not have a path component. So something like `http://localhost:5000/myoauth` is more conventional. That's not to say that an empty path is impossible, simply that it's so unusual that it's more probable you have misunderstood OAuth somewhere.

However, note that you can configure several redirect URLs, so `http://local:5000` *and* `https://localhost:5000` *and* `https://myliveservice.com/redirect`